# Spring Command Line App hangs after Async method calls complete

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application that uses `CommandLineRunner` and the Spring `@Async` annotation to run a method asynchronously. It all works fine, but when all of my threads complete, the application just hangs instead of exiting.

Here is a minimal example of what I have in my application:

**Application.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationStartup.java**:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AsyncService asyncService;

    @Inject
    public ApplicationStartup(final AsyncService asyncService) {
        this.asyncService = asyncService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final String... strings) throws Exception {
        //my logic is more complicated than this, but this illustrates my point
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            asyncService.runAsyncMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

**AsyncService.java**:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AsyncService {

    @Async
    public void runAsyncMethod() {
        //perform call to an API and process results
    }

}
```

**ExecutorConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig() {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(64);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(64);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Scrub-");
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(60);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

All of my threads make the call to `runAsyncMethod()` and every method call completes successfully, but then the application just hangs.

I tried changing some of the executor settings around. I didn't have the `keepAliveSeconds` at first, so I thought adding that would fix it, but it still hung after all threads were complete. I changed `corePoolSize` to `0`, and that made the application exit when it was done, but it only used 1 thread the whole time.

Any ideas as to why the application is not exiting with the configuration above?

Comment: Actually I suspect that the cmdrunner#run exits *before* the async methods complete...think about joining your threads in the run method! (example : https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-async-method/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/AppRunner.java)

Comment: Had to do `myCollection.toArray(new CompletableFuture[myCollection.size()])`.

Comment: But after doing the `join()` it goes back to my main thread and executes the `logger.debug()` statement I have in there, but then still hangs in the main thread...

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just had to wait 60 seconds for the final thread to close because of my `keepAliveSeconds` being set to 60

Comment: @xerx593 This worked perfectly! If you want to type that out as an answer, including some snippets of the example you referenced, I'll accept it.

Comment: With Spring Boot, you can also try to lower the value of `spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive` (default is 60s), to exit quicker. See [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to *join* the asynchronous jobs, that's why the `run` method exits (far) before all threads complete - and the awkward behavior is "more comprehensible".

According to [doc](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-async-method/blob/2.1.6.RELEASE/complete/src/main/java/hello/AppRunner.java), you could join like:

```
...
CompletableFuture<Void>[] myJobs = new CompletableFuture<>[N];
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        myJobs[i] = asyncService.runAsyncMethod();
}
...
CompletableFuture.allOf(myJobs).join();
```

And your `runAsyncMethod()` would need to return a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. To do so, you can just `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);`

Comment: The OP asked why his application hangs, not why it exists early

Comment: i don't know! (why it hangs/exits early) The OP is happy & "ordered" this answer (to accept it), what is the/your problem, @HairOfTheDog?

Comment: After adding the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to make my async methods run ...well... asynchronously the `public static void main()` method started hanging. (Similar to OP, but I am using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instead of `SpringApplication` to initialize the Spring container.) I was hoping to learn what magic Spring does and the proper way to make it exit.

Comment: please post a new question (with your configuration details), @HairOfTheDog (and point me to it ..i will also try to help you to solve it;)  ...in *this case* the issue could be fixed by "joining the jobs".

Comment: I can not create an array like this: CompletableFuture<Void>[] myJobs = new CompletableFuture<>[N];
Error:(44, 66) java: cannot create array with '<>' Using java 13

Comment: Thanks I could solve this in the same second by using:

List<CompletableFuture<Void>> results = new ArrayList<>(N);
CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.allOf(results.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))).join();

Comment: just: `CompletableFuture<Void>[] myJobs = new CompletableFuture<Void>[N]`, @DominikK  (use `<Void>` instead of `<>` ;)

Comment: Using this line I had no luck: CompletableFuture<Void>[] test = new CompletableFuture<Void>[execCount];
So a list was my only solution

Comment: For the future generation, there also could be a bug in IntelliJ, this is working when running unit tests but not when running the application normally on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the [marked as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46794654/449553) answer is valid. This is not full answer.

Without `@EnableAsync` and without WEB environment `.web(WebApplicationType.NONE)` the spring boot app automatically stop once started(as there is nothing to do/wait). So even if you don't do `apringApp.close()` in your app but only `app.run(commandLine)`, the `.close()` method call automatically.

But once you added `@EnableAsync` - the behavior changes, as there might be async work, so app is not stopped once started. And if there is not stopping code, the app remain working (hangs).

For fixing this you need to do 2 things:

- [in the run method do wait all async work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46794654/449553)
- implicitly call `.close()`after app started

Sample:

```java
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableAsync
    public static class SpringApp extends SpringApplication {

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor () {
            return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        }

        @Autowired
        private Service service;

        @EventListener
        public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event){
            CompletableFuture<Void> aggregateFuture = service.doWork();
            // avoid exiting this method before all job complected prevents app from hanging
            aggregateFuture.join();

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringApp.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        app.run()
           .close();  // <--- THIS!
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is crucial to call the `close()` method.